# Incorrect result of comparison in batch file

Tags: batch-file

this batch:

```
@echo off
set _ping_cmd=ping -n 1 192.168.1.1

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,60) DO (

    FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=(=" %%G IN ('%_ping_cmd% ^|find "loss"') DO (
        echo Result is [%%G]
        IF  %%G == " 0 " GOTO ON
    )
    timeout 60
)

:ON
```

produced this output:

```
D:\>live

Result is [ 0 ]

Waiting for 52 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

Why? Obviously, the `%%G` IS `" 0 "`, but `goto` is not executed..

Comment: You're reusing the same variable name for both FOR calls. This is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Obviously, the `%%G` IS `" 0 "`, but `goto` is not executed..

You need quotes around `%%G` as follows:

```
IF  "%%G" == " 0 " GOTO ON
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)